Docker Django MariaDB - "Can't connect to server on 'dj1_mariadb'"
Here's folder structure:
 Dockerfile
 .env
 requirements.txt
 pr/
   static/
     app.js
   manage.py
   pr/
     wsgi.py
     __init__.py
     urls.py
     settings.py
     asgi.py
 docker-compose.yml

Here the important file's content
Dockerfile
---------
# Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM python:3.11

# Set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
       gcc \
       libmariadb-dev \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Upgrade pip
RUN pip install --upgrade pip

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Install Python dependencies
COPY requirements.txt /app/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Copy the project code into the container
COPY ./pr /app/
# Expose the Django development server port
EXPOSE 8000

requirements.txt
---------
psycopg2>=2.8
asgiref==3.8.1
Django==5.1.1
djangorestframework==3.15.2
mysqlclient==2.2.4
python-dotenv==1.0.1
sqlparse==0.5.1
pytz==2024.2

settings.py:
....
# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': os.environ.get('MYSQL_DATABASE'),
        'USER': os.environ.get('MYSQL_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('MYSQL_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': 'dj1_mariadb',
        'PORT': 3306,
    }
}
....

docker-compose.yml:
services:

  dj1_mariadb:
    image: mariadb:latest
    container_name: dj1_mariadb
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: myrpass
      MYSQL_DATABASE: dj1
      MYSQL_USER: ab_usr
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: mypass
    volumes:
      - ./data/mariadb:/var/lib/mysql
      # apt-get update && apt-get install -y mariadb-client
    networks:
      - app-network

  dj1_pma:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: dj1_pma
    restart: always
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: dj1_mariadb
      PMA_USER: ab_usr
      PMA_PASSWORD: mypass
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    depends_on:
      - dj1_mariadb
    networks:
      - app-network


  dj1_web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: dj1_web
    command: >
      sh -c "python3 manage.py collectstatic --noinput && python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./pr:/app
      - ./pr/static:/app/static
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=dj1
      - MYSQL_USER=ab_usr
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=mypass
    depends_on:
      - dj1_mariadb
    networks:
      - app-network

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge

Can somebody help me? http://localhost:8080/ works well. But the docker django cannot connect the to the database:
my@host:~/dj1$ docker-compose run dj1_web python3 manage.py inspectdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 279, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 256, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 256, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 121, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 195, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
MySQLdb.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to server on 'dj1_mariadb' (115)")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/app/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 436, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 413, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 459, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/inspectdb.py", line 47, in handle
    for line in self.handle_inspection(options):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/inspectdb.py", line 60, in handle_inspection
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 320, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 296, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 278, in ensure_connection
    with self.wrap_database_errors:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 279, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 256, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 256, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 121, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 195, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to server on 'dj1_mariadb' (115)")


Does the same issue happen when you run django again by running the 'docker-compose restart dj1_web' command with mysql running?

I don't understand very well. I use comnands like "docker-compose down; docker-compose up -d --build  --remove-orphans". phpmyadmin in my own host localhost:8080 works well. After the command i use also "docker-compose run dj1_web python3 manage.py inspectdb" for seeing the connection. After this command it displays the errors. And django site url localhost:8000 in my ubuntu wsl also is crashed.

WSL can be problematic.

A depends_on relationship only requires the dependency be started, but its not necessary ready as the "Can't connect to server" would indicate in your case.
On way is to use the MariaDB healthcheck.sh script.
services:

  dj1_mariadb:
    image: mariadb:latest
    container_name: dj1_mariadb
    restart: always
    environment:
      MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: myrpass
      MARIADB_DATABASE: dj1
      MARIADB_USER: ab_usr
      MARIADB_PASSWORD: mypass
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "healthcheck.sh", "--connect", "--innodb_initialized"]
      start_period: 10s
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 3
    volumes:
      - ./data/mariadb:/var/lib/mysql

  dj1_pma:
...
    depends_on:
      dj1_mariadb:
        condition: service_healthy

  dj1_web:
       ...
    depends_on:
      dj1_mariadb:
        condition: service_healthy


If this isn't the case, look at the logs on dj1_mariadb to see why it didn't start. Also see the FAQ.
